Notepad++ : Replace digits [0-9] for the same digits
I'm trying using this pattern \s[0-9]+\. in "Find what" , but I want to keep the same original numbers in "Replace with" in order to break text into paragraghs.
What code should I put in "Replace with" to give me back the same numbers? I've tried \n\d\. and \s[0-9]+\. but it's a bit confusing for me the replacement syntax.
For example, I need to turn a text like:

1.1 Text 2.3 Text 3. Ordered List break

Into this:

1.1 Text
2.3 Text

Ordered List break



i dont know notepadd++ but from a regex point of view, you want to create a capture group around the number using (). And then reference it. Depending on the regex parser for example with \1 for the first capture group.

Find: (([0-9]+[\.])([0-9]+[\.\s])?), Replace with: \r$1 like in this: https://regex101.com/r/qNnI3s/1

Now I comprehend how this works
